# Callbacks with different parameter types and storing the type

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

I have a communication library, that should invoke callbacks (or handlers) based on a received command type. I am storing handlers in a `std::map` (command as a key, handler as a value).

These handlers need to have different parameter types. There is always only one handler parameter, and this parameter inherits from`BaseType`. So I have following typedefs and handlers:

```
class Comm {
    typedef std::function<void(BaseType*)> Handler;
    typedef std::map<Command, Handler> Handlers;

    void HandleHandshake(IntType*); // IntType inherits from BaseType
};
```

Unfortunately I cannot store handler `HandleHandshake` in the `Handlers` type. I can only store a handler that has parameter of type `BaseType*`. I cannot use `std::function<void()>` to bind different arguments since I need to have access to its `argument_type` (Otherwise I wouldn't be able to pass proper data type when invoking the handler.).

Is there any way of achieving what I want to achieve? (Storing handlers of different parameter types, and also storing the type for further use.)

To show example of calling the handler:

```
// I parsed a command. Handler of this command should take IntType as a parameter.
m_Handlers[cmd](IntType(some_data));
// But, I don't really know that it is IntType, I only have my map of handlers.
// I want something like this:
m_Handlers[cmd](m_Handlers[cmd]::argument_type(some_data));
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. 1. You receive `some_data` along with `cmd` when you are ordered to invoke a specific command. 2. `some_data` can be of different types (e.g. int, float). 3. To pass it into your "invoke command" method you use a template.

Comment: BTW. You can always use a very unsafe and [evil](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/big-picture#defn-evil) `void*` and `static_cast` `some_data` back and forth without adding a layer of wrappers. P.S. DON'T do it until I say there is no better way.

Comment: How many different argument types the system is required to support? 5? 10? 100? unknown number (i.e. can be extended by the user of the library)?

Comment: How many different messages the system is required to support? <same questions>

Comment: The root problem is that your handler-map contains handlers-of-X. You  upcast them to fit the `function<void(Basetype*)>` signature, which erases the information you need to pass in the right argument. The only thing tying together the right type and your argument is you implying they match up. To fix, either make a lambda that dynamic_casts to the right type and passes on, static_cast to pass on, or don't type erase to start with (and match them in template storage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always store a lambda that does a `static_cast`. For example:

```
template <typename T=BaseType, typename F>
void store(Command c, F function)
{
     Handlers[c] = [function](BaseType* obj){
         function(static_cast<T*>(obj));
     });
}
```

Comment: I don't think this can be used as I need it to. I need to know the type at the moment of invoking the handler, so that I can create it for it.

Comment: @TomášOndruš So you can what?

Comment: Invoke meant as a request. Read it _calling the handler_.

Comment: @TomášOndruš I still don't understand what it is you want. Can you add some examples to the question to clarify?

Comment: Added example of calling the handler.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on something similar before. This is what I would do:

```
typedef std::function<void(BaseType*)> Handler;
typedef std::map<Command, Handler> Handlers;
```

Then I would have each handler take a pointer to BaseType* so that I can store it in my map.

```
void MyIntHandler(BaseType* b)
{
    // we know what kind of information should be passed into this method
    // so we can just cast to the correct type
    auto data = static_cast<IntType*>(b);

    // do something with data
}

void MyStringHandler(BaseType* b)
{
    auto data = static_cast<StringType*>(b);
    // ...
}
```

You can't store a type object like you can in C# and then use it to create objects of that type. You can use [typeinfo](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/) to get some information about a particular type at runtime.

Comment: So there is no way I could have typedef for the exact type? Lets say some wrapper around my std::function.

Comment: @TomášOndruš He is right and he is wrong. C++ is a very powerful language if you know how to use it. Though the type isn't an object in C++ and you can't store it, you can implement a very similar behavior with a clever use of templates.